# C - Linked List Concatenation Runs into malloc Error

Tags: c, linked-list, concatenation

I have been having trouble creating a `concat();` function, it works, but when I go ahead and free the lists, I get a `malloc` error... I am positive I am freeing my list correctly, when I do not run my `concat();` function the list gets freed correctly. Which is my reason to believe I am doing something wrong in this function...

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;


struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};


   void lst_concat(LIST *a, LIST *b) {
if( !( a->front && b->front)) return ;

if (a->front == NULL && b->back == NULL) {

    return;
}

if (a->front == NULL && b->front != NULL) {
    a->front = b->front;
    return;
}
else{
NODE *tmp = a->front;
    if( a->back == NULL )return;
    if( a->front == NULL )return;
    if( b->back == NULL )return;
    if( b->front == NULL )return;
    else{
    NODE *tempPtr = a->back;

    tempPtr->next=b->front;
    tempPtr = b->front;
    a->back = b->back;
    }
}}
void lst_free(LIST *l) {
NODE *p = l->front;
NODE *pnext;

  while(p!= NULL) {
    pnext = p->next;   // keeps us from de-referencing a freed ptr
    free(p);
    p = pnext;
  }
  // now free the LIST 
  free(l);
}
```

**UPDATE, this updates list a correctly, however, can I still free both lists, or can I only free one since they are joined? my `lst_free()` is above.

Comment: a->back = a->back; doesn't look right

Comment: @bruceg I apologize I don't know how that got there... its suppose to be 'b' its fixed, but the function still won't work properly..

Comment: @milevyo I'm not sure what you're asking, sorry!:(

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a **Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There are several bugs here. I think your problem is more fundamental - show all code... For instance `LIST`....

Comment: start by providing us the `struct LIST` then what you want to do with `cancat`

Comment: @4386427 added my struct

Comment: @milevyo added struct

Comment: You are still dereferencing `a` without checking for `NULL` Here: `if(a->front ==NULL ....` What if `a` is `NULL` - bad luck

Comment: @LearningCODE, you can not just concat two lists like that. what is the purpose to do that?

Comment: @milevyo I added some info to the main post

Comment: in `lst_free` you are freeing only `->front` what about `->back`,

Answer (score 1):

this is the only rational way that i can imagine (so far) ...

```
typedef struct NODE         NODE;
typedef struct list_struct  LIST;


typedef struct node {
    ElemType    val;
    NODE        *next;
} NODE;


struct list_struct {
    NODE        *front;
    NODE        *back;
};


// get the ending node
NODE *LastNode(NODE *root){
    NODE *tmp = NULL;
    while(root){
        tmp  = root;
        root = root->next;
   }
   return tmp;
}


// this will move node from pnode
// and put it at the end of proot nodes
void move_node(NODE **proot,NODE **pnode){

    if(! (pnode && proot) )
        return; // no comments

    if(pnode == proot)
        return; // no comments

    NODE *node = *pnode;
    NODE *root = *proot;
    NODE *tmp;

    if(!node) return;

    if(!root){
        // this node becomes the first one
        *proot      = node;
    }else{
        // this node becomes the last node
        LastNode(root)->next = node;
    }

    // now nodes blongs to other node
    // set this to NULL
    *pnode = NULL;

}


// this will move a nodes to b;
// 
void lst_concat(LIST *a, LIST *b) {
    move_node(&a->front, &b->front);
    move_node(&a->back, &b->back);
    // at this point b has no front, and no back
    // all has been moved to a

}


void free_nodes(NODE **proot){
    if ( !(proot && *proot) )
        return;

    NODE *root = *proot;

    if( root->next)
        free_nodes(&root->next);

    free(root);
    *proot=NULL;
}

void lst_free(LIST *l) {
    if( l ) {
        free_nodes( &l->front);
        free_nodes( &l->back);
        free(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: beside those donwvote Ninjaaaas. ( they are cool any way). @LearningCODE  can you explain how you plan to resolve this situation???, what should i do?

Comment: Not that I know but perhaps your introduction `I couldn't get a logical solution` is bad - either you know and post a good solution or you don't know and don't post.

Comment: @4386427, how you think i can put this whole code in a comment?. i wanted him to understand where the problem resides.

Comment: @milevyo My program works but when the lists get freed there is a malloc error `pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug` in my `lst_free` function

Comment: I did not use this code, however, you reminded me to make the LIST *b = NULL at the end... this was my issue thank you for indirectly helping :D

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing `a` before knowing whether it is `null` Here:

```
void concat(LIST *a, LIST *b)
{
    if (a->front == NULL) { // !!!! what if a is NULL? Crash...
        a->front = b->front; 
        a->back = b->back;
        return;
    }
```

Check for `a` being `NULL`first.

You are also dereferencing `b` before knowing whether it is `null` Here:

```
void concat(LIST *a, LIST *b)
{
    if (a->front == NULL) {
        a->front = b->front; // !!!! what if b is NULL? Crash...
        a->back = b->back;
        return;
    }
```

At least do:

```
void concat(LIST *a, LIST *b)
{
    if (a == NULL)  // This needs to go first, i.e. before dereferencing a
    {
         // some code
    }

    // other code ....
}
```